# Is there a keyword for getting the latest AWS IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Hi I am currently working with boto3 and want to get the latest IAM policy document.

I am using the following boto3 library call

```
policy_version = client.get_policy_version(
PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::833926522372:policy/test-fake-fawkes-policy',
VersionId="v1"    //Wondering if I can put something like 'latest'
)
```

Comment: Only option appears to be to list the policy versions and determine which has the latest create date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no feature like this right now :(

I tried and got a response from the library call

```
Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: v[1-9][0-9]*(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]*
```